# What are some different ways to retrieve btc transaction information of an address using bitcoinjs?

Tags: api, javascript, bitcoinjs, library

What are some different ways to retrieve btc transaction information of an address using bitcoinjs?

I've tried using the syntax from this page (https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.spec.ts) but didn't seem to work it out.

Any specific suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoinjs is a software library, it is not a node and it does not connect to the network. The address typescript file you have linked is for creating addresses. If you want bitcoin transaction data such an unspent outputs you'll need to do that on your own or use a 3rd party API.